# Display special characters with pipe dilemeter

Tags: java, regex

I'm playing around with Java RegEx and trying to think of different scenarios for string manipulation.  I can strip out special characters from a string with the following:

```
String test = "A man,  66  a plan, a can*()al:55 Panama";
String test = test.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(test);
```

Output:   ,     ,  *():

What if I wanted those special characters returned with a pipe delimiter?  So, the expected output would be:  ,|,|*|(|)|:|

Comment: Maybe `test.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+", "|")`?

Comment: Close, but it doesn't work for special characters that are right next to each other.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/bx2sDr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and extract these symbols other than alphanumeric and whitespace into a list and the join its elements with `|`:

```
String test = "A man,  66  a plan, a can*()al:55 Panama";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]").matcher(test);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    results.add( m.group() );
}
System.out.println(String.join("|", results));
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wuX6s7) yielding `,|,|*|(|)|:`.

Comment: I've never used the utility String.join() before.  Very handy.  Thanks again brother.